# Error 401 Unauthorized connecting with Marvel API

Tags: api

I've created a new account to use the Marvel API's, but I'm having some trouble to make calls to it.

> I've generated a hash based on these parameters:

```
timestamp: 1561464418685
public key: 3e6f6a484529014f288cc251191b85d0
private key: 0e70d6990a8135b5409ede2cbab3a9e913c6b9c3
```

> So I've concatenated the parameters into a single string like this:

`15614644186850e70d6990a8135b5409ede2cbab3a9e913c6b9c33e6f6a484529014f288cc251191b85`d0

> and then applied MD5 hash, returning the following hash:

```
57d62328aea6fb144458312efbdf7989
```

> and finally, the complete call:

```
https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1561464418685&apikey=3e6f6a484529014f288cc251191b85d0&hash=57d62328aea6fb144458312efbdf7989
```

But the only return I'm getting is the following:

```
{"code":"InvalidCredentials","message":"This user is not allowed to use that service."}
```

I'm trying to make the request on browser(Chrome) and Postman.

Here is a print of my account configuration on Marvel Developer Panel, it seems that my user isn't really allowed to make the calls to the API, cause the number os API calls isn't displayed.

Any hint would be very useful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wasn't allowed to attach a print to my post, sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

As @marcel-konjata noted, I changed my authorized referrers in my `My Developer Account` page. And it worked.

Comment: I already lost a couple of days of struggling with this API. It works, thank you!

Comment: This answer helped. Thanks. `*` will allow requests from any host.

Answer (score 2):

well Even if this a late answer: if you are developing from localhost, you need to add at the myDeveloperAccount at developer.marvel.com at "Your authorized referrers":

IP address at the one colon,
add referer and another one is *localhost* (with asterisks)

found that by coincidence

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and I just created a new account on marvel with a different email and it worked straight away.  Maybe as I had not used the API key in a while it because dis-activated or something.